# Choosing one element from list according to preference

Tags: java

I'm given an unordered list of objects of this form

```java
class Element {
  String property; // has value from the set ("A", "B", "C", "D")
}
```

where no two elements have the same `property` value.
I want to choose one element according to a set of rules like the following and return its `property` value:

1. If there is an element whose `property` has value `"A"`, then pick that element.
2. Else, if there is an element whose `property` has value `"B"`, then pick that element.
3. Else, if there is an element whose `property` has value `"C"`, then pick that element.
4. Finally if no element has been chosen yet, then throw an exception.

This is one solution I've come up with for this problem:

```java
String chooseElementProperty(List<Element> elements) {
  // Iterates the list and creates a set of all the property values.
  // example: [{property: 'A'}, {property: 'B'}] -> {'A', 'B'}
  Set<String> propertyValues = pluckPropertyValues(elements);

  if (propertyValues.contains("A"))
    return "A";
  if (propertyValues.contains("B"))
    return "B";
  if (propertyValues.contains("C"))
    return "C";
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input!");
}
```

My question is: What is a better/cleaner way to do this that makes this method more extensible where it's easier to change my preference if in the future I want to choose `"B"` over `"A"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than having the desired property values hard-coded into `chooseElementProperty`, provide them in an additional argument:

```
String chooseElementProperty(List<Element> elements, List<String> prefs) {
  // Iterates the list and creates a set of all the property values.
  // example: [{property: 'A'}, {property: 'B'}] -> {'A', 'B'}
  Set<String> propertyValues = pluckPropertyValues(elements);

  for (String s: prefs) {
      if (propertyValues.contains(s))
          return s;
  }
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input!");
}
```

Here I've used a `List<String>`, but you could also use a `String[]` or even a `String...` varargs if you prefer.

Comment: Adding a for loop can be avoided to improve performance here. `O(n)` compared to `O(1)`

Comment: @PritamBanerjee pretty sure it was already `O(n)` (or worse!) before, but not `O(1)`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming all the property values are letters, you can sort the list and provide a `comparator` to sort by `propery` then validate the property of the first item

```
Collections.sort(elements, new Comparator<Element>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Element a, Element b) {
        return a.property.compareTo(b.property);
    }
});
List<String> check = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
String tmp = elements.get(0).property;
if check.contains(tmp) 
    return tmp
else
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input!");
```

You can also sort using lambda:

```
Collections.sort(elements, (e1, e1) -> e1.property.compareTo(e2.property));
```

Comment: As pointed out in the last sentence of the question: It should be possible to change the order of the preferences (to something not-alphabetical)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List<String> targets = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
return elements.stream()
  .map(this::pluckPropertyValues)
  .flatMap(Set::stream)
  .filter(targets::contains)
  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(targets::indexOf))
  .findFirst()
  .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
```

This will work for an arbitrary list of targets, with preferences based on their position in the list.

<sub>Disclaimer: Code may not compile or work as it was thumbed in on my phone (but there's a reasonable chance it will work)</sub>

Comment: No offense, but I just looked into your profile to see whether you may just be in your [fifth year of programming](https://medium.com/@webseanhickey/the-evolution-of-a-software-engineer-db854689243). Subjectively, this is an overly ["clever"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/350230) solution to a fairly trivial task. Objectively, sorting with a comparator involving `indexOf` is somewhere way beyond O(n^2). Speculatively, the reference to `this::pluckPropertyValues` would have to be `e -> e.property`

Comment: @marco this about as simple as it gets. Ask yourself how many lines of code need to be added to support more target values... answer: none. All the method calls (or their equivalent) are needed in any implementation (except the sort) - they have just been organised here as stream steps. Regarding the sort, unless the number of elements is huge you won't feel it but it simplifies the logic and code to one statement.

Comment: I know this isn't code golf, but instead of `.orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new)`, you could just use `.get()`, which throws `NoSuchElementException` if the `Optional` is empty.  Nice Java8 stream solution.

Answer (score 2):

The current answers seem to assume that the order is `"A", "B", "C"`, and thus, may have overlooked the last, crucial statement:

> What is a better/cleaner way to do this that makes this method more extensible where it's easier to change my preference if in the future I want to choose `"B"` over `"A"`?

Beyond that, the solutions may be considered as ... "tricky" ... or complex, from a computational point of view. I'd vote for a solution that is similar to yours, but without the creation of the list of properties, and basically just puts the preferences into a list to iterate over it:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class Element
{
    String property;

    Element(String property)
    {
        this.property = property;
    }
}
public class PickByPreference
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Element> elements = Arrays.asList(
            new Element("B"),
            new Element("C"),
            new Element(null),
            new Element("A"));
        System.out.println(chooseElementProperty(elements));
    }

    static String chooseElementProperty(List<Element> elements) 
    {
        // Change this to change the preferences
        // (or pass it in as a parameter)
        List<String> preferences = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");

        for (String preference : preferences)
        {
            for (Element element : elements)
            {
                if (preference.equals(element.property))
                {
                    return element.property;
                }
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input!");
    }
}
```

---

Edit: In terms of asymptotic complexity, extracting the properties into a `Set` may be beneficial, though, particularly if you have *many* elements. In this case, the implementation would be

```
static String chooseElementProperty(List<Element> elements) 
{
    // Change this to change the preferences
    // (or pass it in as a parameter)
    List<String> preferences = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
    Set<String> propertyValues = pluckPropertyValues(elements);
    for (String preference : preferences)
    {
        if (propertyValues.contains(preference))
        {
            return element.property;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are correct.

My two cents would be to avoid `contains()` as it uses `indexOf()`

So use

```
if (propertyValues.indexOf("A") > -1)
   return "A";
if (propertyValues.indexOf("B") > -1)
   return "B";
if (propertyValues.indexOf("C") > -1)
   return "C";
```

Comment: The term "above" depends on the sort order of the answers, which may change. Beyond that, `contains(x)` and `indexOf(x) > -1` are equivalent, but the first one is more clear and readable - so why did you propose this change?